# Java Generics - method after type erasure

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

How will the following method look after applying type erasure?

```
static<T> void InsertAt0(List<T> mylist, T element) {
    mylist.add(0, element);
}
```

will `T` be replaced with `Object`? or maybe type-erasure is only about generics classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove all of the `<T>`s, and then replace any `T` with Object:

```
static void InsertAt0(List mylist, Object element) {
   mylist.add(0, element);
}
```

Note that mylist above has been erased to its [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) equivalent: `List<T>` became just `List`.

If you had specified a wildcard bound for T, like `<T extends Number>`, then you would replace `T` with that bound instead of Object:

```
static void InsertAt0(List mylist, Number element) {
                                   ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Just to add, notice List<Something> is erased, and becomes a List. Take a look at this link OP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure